# Deduplicate Delta Table while Merging

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, delta-lake

I have a delta table in Azure and a dataframe. The dataframe has duplicates in it and want it so that those duplicates aren't added to the delta table when they are merged. I know that I can remove the duplicates before the merger, but I want to know if it's possible to do it during the merger. I have an example below.

Org Delta Table

```
1, "abc", 45678
2, "def", 89076
3, "lop", 90678
```

New incoming data - dataframe

```
4, "abc", 98067 --- partition 1
4, "abc", 98067 --- partition 2
4, "abc", 98067 --- partition 3
```

Merge two tables as shown

Final table

```
1, "abc", 45678
2, "def", 89076
3, "lop", 90678
4, "abc", 98067 --- THIS ROW SHOULD EXIST ONLY ONCE
```

Edit: I have tried omitting the “whenMatched” when merging but it keeps the duplicates and when i add “when MatchedDelete” it deletes the whole table.